Move app data to external memory
I'm on android 11 rooted with magisk, I downloaded and installed a large game, occupying most of my internal storage (64gb).
How can I link the app data to my external card (128gb) and play the game from there?
No OBB, just a big data folder

Does this answer your question? Link2SD - Game ignores binded data after link
